Sci-Fi Movie, probably 80's, Alien Ship crash lands in small town, releases 3 different alien prisoners
Looking for a movie that featured an alien ship crash-landing in a small town and 3 different alien escaping into town. Local police investigates. Apparently the ship is a prison ship and there is another alien who appears human who helps catch them; the last alien I believe was invisible.
Sci-Fi, probably 80's. The aliens were all different and each alien had to be defeated in a different way. The movie only takes place on Earth, is obscure and not big budget. It's stumped me for decades.

Marked as a duplicate because I'm fairly certain you're looking for The Alien Factor from 1976. If this isn't it, please let me know.

I do believe it is The Alien Factor, I'll watch it on YouTube and see.

This could be Critters from 1986.
Here is the plot partially matching your description (there is no invisible alien involved):

The film begins on a prison set on an asteroid, from which a group of 'Crites' are set to be transported to another station. When the Crites kill two guards and injure three, hijack a ship from the station, and escape, the commander of the station hires two shape-changing bounty hunters to pursue them.
When later on the roof, Brad mistakes the Crites' spaceship for a meteorite. The ship thereafter lands, causing the ground to shake. 
Meanwhile the two bounty hunters search the town.


Thanks for the reply. I checked, wasn't Critters. The movie only takes place on Earth in the small town local police investigate  The aliens were all different and the movie was more obscure less of a budget. It's stumped me for decsdes. Each alien had to be defeated in a different way.
